# Determining if a transfer to a contract is from another contract

Tags: solidity

I have two contracts, 0xA and 0xB, and they both have an attribute 'mate_address' which is the other contracts address. For instance, 0xA's mate_address is 0xB, and 0xB's mate_address is 0xA.

I want to define a function which can be called by any address, in this case 0xC, which will send the balance of one contract to another.

Here are the contracts:

0xA:

```
contract TheContract {
    address public mateAddress = OxB

    function () payable public {
        if (msg.sender == mateAddress) {
            //do something
        }
    }

    function checkStatus() {
        if (someCondition) {
            address myAddress = this;
            mateAddress.send(myAddress.balance);
        }
    }
}
```

0xB:

```
contract TheContract {
    address public mateAddress = OxA

    function () payable public {
        if (msg.sender == mateAddress) {
            //do something
        }
    }

    function checkStatus() {
        if (someCondition) {
            address myAddress = this;
            mateAddress.send(myAddress.balance);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to call the checkStatus function, my transaction gets reversed at the `if (msg.sender == mateAddress)` line.

How could i get the behaviour that I want?

Comment: The `someCondition` is `if (msg.sender == mateAddress)` ?

Comment: is the function definition correct? you have `function () checkStatus` instead of `function checkStatus()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you execute checkStatus in contract A. If the someCondition is fulfilled, you will send the balance of A to B. The payable function will revert because the gas sent using mateAddres.send() is not enough to execute anything else but the transaction (I had this issue a few weeks ago). You can solve this defining the payable function with an argument.

```
contract TheContract_A {
    address public mateAddress = OxB

    function funding(address from) payable public {
        if (from == mateAddress) {
            //do something
        }
    }

    function () checkStatus {
        if (someCondition) {
            TheContract_B instanceOfB = TheContract_B(mateAddres);
            instanceOfB.funding.value(address(this).balance)(address(this));
        }
    }
}

contract TheContract_B {
    address public mateAddress = OxA

    function funding(address from) payable public {
        if (from == mateAddress) {
            //do something
        }
    }

    function () checkStatus {
        if (someCondition) {
            TheContract_A instanceOfA = TheContract_A(mateAddres);
            instanceOfA.funding.value(address(this).balance)(address(this));
        }
    }
}
```

What I have done is to make an interaction between the contracts. A will call the funding function (payable) in B with an argument which will increase the allowed gas, then you can execute more code in this call. The same for contract B.

This line:

```
TheContract_B instanceOfB = TheContract_B(mateAddres);
```

creates an instance of B in A to be able to access B functions, and this line:

```
instanceOfB.funding.value(address(this).balance)(address(this));
```

will execute the funding function in B including a transaction of ether from A with value `address(this).balance`

As for the reason of the gas limit you will read in the docs (solidity)

> address.transfer(uint256 amount): send given amount of Wei to
>   Address, throws on failure, forwards 2300 gas stipend, not adjustable.
>
> address.send(uint256 amount) returns (bool): send given amount of
>   Wei to Address, returns false on failure, forwards 2300 gas stipend,
>   not adjustable

Is not the same when the ether is sent from an account. In the transfer from Ether from an account you can send more gas.

Also, slightly unrelated, I think is safer to use `transfer` rather than `send` in future contracts.

I hope this helps.